# Rule Base for Java enabled workflow system

Tags: java, workflow, drools, rule

I am designing a generic system that should have capability to

1. fetch relevant records from database for given input.
2. fetch set of rules applicable on given input.
3. filter records based on rules.

I envision my system to keep rule execution in itself and not delegate it to a rule engine like Drools, hence - I need inputs on available libraries - that will allow me to STORE/ADD/UPDATE/MANAGE_CONFLICTS and finally FETCH_RELEVANT rules.

Questions : Available libraries to create a rule base and allow fast search on them ?

```
     _________________          ___________          __________________________
    |                 |  fast  |           |        |                          |
    | Workflow System |--------| Rule Base |--------| User interface for rules |
    |_________________| search |___________|        |__________________________|
```

Use Case : Imagine a graph with node as cities and edges as connections. Two nodes can be linked via several edges (train, air, road etc) each having its own cost and time constraints. Input is source node and destination node. Rules may be like : Pay octroi charges while in city X, Prefer air route between X and Y only when road and train route is not available etc.

PS : My workflow will fetch data from a tree graph for input (source-destination pair). It will then apply set of rules applicable on each node, each edge on the path joining source destination.

PS : I went through open problems in CS like multicommodity demand flow problem on trees/graphs which are NP hard and have similar definitions, but my system is trying to solve the problem even it is sub optimal solution.

Comment: This isn't a question according to the format acceptable for stackoverflow. In particular, tagging with "Drools" which you explicitly exclude from the envisaged solution is misleading and annoying.

Comment: Hey - apologies if that was misleading. Actually - I wanted that - folks who used Drools may help me with other options that were considered by them while their project began.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if [Rulette](https://github.com/kislayverma/Rulette) serves your purpose. It runs "within" your application and rules are easily configured in MySql.

**Edit**

You can do this

1. Add rulette-core to your project's dependencies.
2. Set up rulette as the documentation explains.
3. Rule inputs can be source city, dest. city, and mode of travel (going only by the examples you gave), their combinations mapping to different rule output.
4. For rule outputs, you can use strings( or any other ids) which map to executor classes in your code. These classes contain the business logic of doing what needs to be done.

This should solve your intent of keeping the rule evaluation within your application and also keeping the actual activities decoupled from the rules of invocation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12513483)

Comment: Edited the answer to be a little more comprehensive.